# Retrieving denormalized data in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm new to firebase and learned that I should save my data in a denormalized way. I am saving some goals written by users. And I'm allowing other users to add comments. That's working well. Whenever a user submits a comment, the comment gets saved in comments node and the goal also gets updated by adding a key to the related comments ID.

```
**comments**
    -LmkoRGfB5GX4Q8NKkBz
    -LmkoTE3sdM3_PYuEtco
        comment-text: "another comment"
        time: 87293862
   -LmlUwUdsUVH5ymTXDoj
   -LmlyU2drjD6gI7GGZzp

**goals**
   -user1
       goalID1
          comments
            -LmkoTE3sdM3_PYuEtco: true
          goal: "I struggle to wake up on time"
          plan: "I will definitely wake up when the alarm clock ..."
```

I can't figure out how to retrieve the comments when I retrieve the information about the goal. Here is how I am retrieving info about the goal. How do I add a loop to get the info about the comments?

```
firebase.database().ref('/goals/' + req.body.userId).orderByChild(goalId).equalTo("goalID1").on('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((item) => {
        items.push({
          key: item.key,
          goal: item.val().goal,
          plan: item.val().plan,
          comments:item.val().comments
        });
      });

      res.status(200).json(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
firebase.database().ref('/goals/' + req.body.userId).orderByChild(goalId).equalTo("goalID1").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let promises = [];
  var item;
  snapshot.forEach((item) => {
    item = {
      key: item.key,
      goal: item.val().goal,
      plan: item.val().plan,
      comments: []
    }
    snapshot.child('comments').forEach((commentKey) => {
      let promise = firebase.database().ref('comments').child(commentKey.key).once('value');
    });
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
    snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      item.comments.push(snapshot.val());
    })
    items.push(item);
    res.status(200).json(items);
  })
```

Some syntax and scope errors are possible, but this should be the rough idea: you load each comment in a loop, and thus have to wait for all comments to be loaded before sending a response to the caller.